# C# simple encryption

Tags: c#, encryption

Hi' I'm learning C# (as a hobbyist) and am trying to figure how to write a simple encryption program.

Converting characters from ASCII is fine, got that sorted, but it is the shift I am stuck on. If I want to code for (n + 3) for example, what line of thought should I be following?

Comment: Yes it is the Caesar cypher I'm after. Sorry for the vague question!

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to do something like a Caesar cipher? (i.e. take every letter and shift it a certain number of letters to the left or right?)

If so, you will want to work with individual characters on your string. There's a datatype char that allows this, and you can do arithmetic operations. To get an array of chars from a string, call (string).ToCharArray(). Then you can iterate through the characters and shift each character.

```
char key = (char)3;
string toEncrypt = "abcdef";
char[] cArray = toEncrypt.ToCharArray();

for (var i = 0; i < cArray.Length; i++) {
   cArray[i] = (char)(cArray[i] + key);
}
```

One thing to keep in mind is that you'll need to "wrap" your characters if they go past the end of the alphabet. I'll leave this as a challenge to you. :)

Keep in mind that while this is a fun way to learn the language, it's not useful in the real world for encryption and is extremely easily broken.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of encryption options built into the .net framework.  Since you are hobbying around, maybe you want to do it by hand, but your test program could simply use the framework.

[System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx)

Also could use the [Cryptography Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511721.aspx)

Perhaps using these is more than you need, but using built in frameworks to meet your goal may help teach you the .net framework and c# as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is a [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher)

> In cryptography, a Caesar cipher, also
>   known as a Caesar's cipher, the shift
>   cipher, Caesar's code or Caesar shift,
>   is one of the simplest and most widely
>   known encryption techniques. It is a
>   type of substitution cipher in which
>   each letter in the plaintext is
>   replaced by a letter some fixed number
>   of positions down the alphabet. For
>   example, with a shift of 3, A would be
>   replaced by D, B would become E, and
>   so on. The method is named after
>   Julius Caesar, who used it to
>   communicate with his generals.

This is a good way to start learning, but please read the section on **Breaking the cipher**

You could try something like

```
string val = "abc";
string encrypt = "";
for (int iChar = 0; iChar < val.Length; iChar++)
{
    encrypt += (char)(val[iChar] + 3);
}
string decrypt = "";
for (int iChar = 0; iChar < encrypt.Length; iChar++)
{
    decrypt += (char)(encrypt[iChar] - 3);
}
```

Another simple option to look at is

[Simple XOR Encryption](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/8b53894c-a889-4914-8c46-122980cc44ae/simple-xor-encryption.aspx)

> What that means is that you only need
>   one method, "EncryptDecrypt". Pass a
>   string into it and get it back
>   encrypted. Pass the encrypted string
>   into it and you get back the original
>   text, as long as the XOR character is
>   the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `(char)('n' + 3)` could give you the character you are looking for and then you can convert it to number once again, as you like..

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't trying to roll your own encryption, the framework has got encryption functionality built in. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163884.aspx) for more info.

edit: fixed link